# How can I prevent Leaflet from moving my marker while zooming into the map?

Tags: leaflet, markers

If I use the leaflet code described in the documentation, use another marker url AND change the iconSize, the marker moves when zoomed in/out.

It doesn't move if I keep the iconSize as it is. But than the marker looks like crap.

This is the original Leaflet code:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'my-icon.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});
L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```

This is how I manipulated it (only coordinated, image url and size are changed):

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iconic/open-iconic/master/png/map-marker-8x.png',
    iconSize: [32, 32],
    iconAnchor: [32, 32],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});

L.marker([52.55, 13.47], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Leaflet doc about [`iconAnchor`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#icon-iconanchor) option:

> The coordinates of the "tip" of the icon (relative to its top left corner). The icon will be aligned so that this point is at the marker's geographical location. Centered by default if size is specified, also can be set in CSS with negative margins.

If you specify `iconAnchor` with the same value as `iconSize` (i.e. `[32, 32]` in your case), Leaflet will position your icon so that its bottom right corner is at the marker's geographic position. Therefore, when zooming in/out, your actual icon "tip" (which is at [bottom center](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iconic/open-iconic/master/png/map-marker-8x.png)) will "move" relatively to that position.

Answer (score 6):

As [ghybs has mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/223056/442), the issue is in the parameters that have been passed to `iconAnchor`.

Given your marker, you need the icon to be Anchored to the bottom center of the icon, for which, the following code should work:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iconic/open-iconic/master/png/map-marker-8x.png',
            iconSize: [32, 32],
            iconAnchor: [16,32]
        });

L.marker([52.55, 13.47], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```

*(Note that I have just removed the options for the shadow, since I do not know which file you have used for it, and where it's anchor point lies. You can add it back, and set the appropriate Anchor point.)*